How to use scipy to find thresholds given predictions
I have training data T containing ground truths of 3 classes C1, C2 and C3. The training data is very small in size (about 1000 rows). Out of 1000 rows, about 700 rows are used for C1, about 250 rows for C2 and only about 50 rows for C3. Since the number of rows for C3 is very low, we don't use multiclass classification but instead use 2 RF models - one to predict C1 and the other to predict both C1 and C3 combined. Let's call these models m1 and m2. The models give predictions pred_m1 and pred_m2 for the predicting C1 and C1 & C3 respectively. Once I have the predictions of 2 models I find 2 thresholds t1 and t2 to find C1, C2 and C3 such that F1 scores of all the three classes are maximized.
def map_preds_to_classes(x):
    if x.pred_m2 < t2:
        return 'C2':
    if x.pred_m2 >= t2 and x.pred_m1 >= t1:
        return 'C1':
    return 'C3'
df['class'] = df.apply(map_preds_to_classes, axis=1)
f1_c1 = f1_score(df['class'] == 'C1', df['ground_truth'] == 'C1')
f1_c2 = f1_score(df['class'] == 'C2', df['ground_truth'] == 'C2')
f1_c3 = f1_score(df['class'] == 'C3', df['ground_truth'] == 'C3')

Is there a way I can use scipy to find t1 and t2 such that f1_c1, f1_c2, and f1_c3 are maximized?
